# Issue related to layout of custom webpart

Tags: kentico

According to requirement of application, I have developed a custom web part in Kentico 9. This web part is using with same functionality at various places but we have to use with different layout structure.
As per my understanding, we can create custom layouts for a single web part from "Layout Tab" in web part configuration. As I used same things with various Kentio built in web part like Logon form, Logon-Mini form, etc.
But while trying to create new layout for my custom web part, I am getting web part loading error and when I checked into event log it is showing following error:

> The file
>   '/CMSVirtualFiles/WebPartLayouts/=vg=87a868ce-926c-4cb3-a441-b4f1d4310afc/TDNForgottenPassword/ForgottenPassword.ascx.cs'
>   does not exist.

Here, internally system looking for ".CS" file under "CMSVirtualFiles" folder, which has actually under the "CMSWebParts" directory in which I have created my user control.

Is there any specific configuration required in custom web part to implement multiple layout of it? Please help me and guide me, what am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check your webpart code file property in the ascx file.  You need to specifically declare the full relative path to the .cs file and not just the filename.  For example:

**Correct**

```
CodeFile="~/CMSWebParts/Community/GroupRegistration.ascx.cs"
```

**Incorrect**

```
CodeFile="GroupRegistration.ascx.cs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you don't have the [store virtual files](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Editing+object+code+externally) in the file system setting enabled.